# Fancytree Tooltip API

Tags: api, tooltip, fancytree

I have been using Fancytree quite successfully for several years. Of late a new requirement has arisen. I would like to change the tooltip for a node that is currently visible. Is there a way to do this? How? Using an API? I have tried changing the tooltip property of an existing Fancytree node. Strangely, this did not work. What will work? Thank you.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**.

Answer (score 0):

Over on Github, this was resolved by Mr. Wendt. He suggested calling node.renderTitle() after modifying node.tooltip (which was correct) and he found a typo in my code. See Github issue #1093